# How to get the custom path(user local path) for file in GWT

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

I have two options to backup my code. One is default path(home/workingDirectory/backup) and another one is custom path. This custom path will be selected by user. If user clicks custom path button or text box the local file selector dialog box is open and get the user's path. I completed the functionality for backup option but I dont know how to get the user selecting path.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons browsers do not allow access to a file path for a selected file.

You can ask a user to choose where to save a file, and then ask a user to upload a file, but you cannot access random directory on a user's hard drive from your app.